# What information does Stack Overflow collect when signing in with OpenID?

Tags: discussion, security, privacy, stack-exchange-openid, user-information

What *exact* information does Stack Overflow collect when signing in with OpenID?

Comment: *Your eternal soul.*

Comment: What about [the privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) is unclear?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing where it talks about what data is collected specifically?

Comment: I think, whatever OpenID provider you're using prompts you as to what you're giving away when registering...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We record the OpenID identifier (which is a URL almost always), and optionally record an email address and personal name if they are provided.  Email and name aren't required, so an OpenID provider that doesn't collect (or send) them will still be accepted.

If an email is provided, we use to connect other accounts on the Stack Exchange network under certain circumstances.  This is to make account merging an automatic thing, as people sometimes forget whether they originally signed in with Google, Facebook, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have not yet read about what OpenIDs are:

> With OpenID, your password is *only given to your identity provider*,
>   and that provider then confirms your identity to the websites you
>   visit. Other than your provider, ***no website ever sees your password***,
>   so you don’t need to worry about an unscrupulous or insecure website
>   compromising your identity.

Following is an excerpt [from here](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/individuals/)

> OpenID is a decentralized standard, meaning it is not controlled by
>   any one website or service provider. You control how much personal
>   information you choose to share with websites that accept OpenIDs.